# Declaring variable without var sign in beginning?

Tags: php, smarty, declaration

I have seen class that states `var _hello_kitty = array();` why they dont use $? i tried to make it `public` and `static` and it does not work without adding `$`i.e. `public static $_hello_kitty = array();`

now when i do add `$` other functions who reference it by `_hello_kitty` stop working.

EDIT: OOOPS was my bad i somehow removed $ from there, i looped up original file and its there. but its still referencing like `$this->_tpl_vars[$tpl_var] = &$value` without $ and i cannot use `self::_tpl_vars[$tpl_var];`

now i did use self::$_tpl_vars[$tpl_var]; but now error comes up `array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array i`

Comment: Yes its inside Smarty php template language file Smarty.class.php its clear php

Comment: Wait - are you assigning variables within your smarty template?

Comment: OOOPS was my bad i somehow removed $ from there, i looped up original file and its there. but its still referencing like             $this->_tpl_vars[$tpl_var] = &$value;

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the mistake, Poemm. Go ahead and `delete` the question. `$this->_tpl_vars[$tpl_var]` is valid php and exactly how you access a member variable.

Comment: You need to read up on the basics of classes and objects in PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: To do what you are doing, you will need to understand PHP classes, objects, and object (and static) references. Please learn more about these concepts in the PHP manual or by going through some books and tutorials. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 1):

You're using smarty and it looks like you're using the PHP 4 notation of class variables:

```
var
```

The PHP 5 representation of it is:

```
public
```

But you don't need to change the code because PHP is backwards compatible. Just leave it as is as a reminder that things change and for your own code you won't make use of `var`.

In case you will actually *need* to change the code because it breaks (and not you break the code because you want to change it), you will notice early enough.

Answer (score 0):

That's how the syntax for PHP class properties works.

You define the property with the dollar-sign, eg

```
public $publicProperty;
protected $protectedProperty;
private $privatePropertyKeepOutLulz;
```

When referencing them from a class instance (ie object), you omit the dollar-sign, eg

```
$obj->publicProperty;
$this->protectedProperty;
$this->privatePropertyKeepOutLulz;
```

### Update

Static properties are declared using the `static` keyword

```
public static $publicStaticProperty;
private static $privateStaticProperty;
```

You then reference them like so

```
// From outside the class (only applies to public properties)
ClassName::$publicStaticProperty;

// From within the class
self::$privateStaticProperty;

// From a descendant class (public or protected only)
parent::$property;
```

Comment: still dont work perhaps if i use $publicProperty;
then other place where it referenced publicProperty will throw error but its okay i will use other approach without need to mess with this class

Comment: @Poemm I have no idea what you're talking about. Please see [Jared's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101064/declaring-variable-without-var-sign-in-beginning/7101134#7101134)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, variables are prefixed with the dollar sign, which is the programming language's [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29). This is an important concept in computing, and it's the only way PHP is able to identify variables.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29) (which never, ever lies):

> In the PHP language, which was largely inspired by Perl, “$” precedes
>   any variable name. Names not prefixed by this are considered constants
>   or functions.

and that's it.